# Google maps API - retrieve data from a layer (json or kml) after autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have designed a map with layer and i must retrieve the data after street autocomplete but i can take the data only from the map click or mousover event:

json layer:

```
map.data.addListener('click', function (event) {               
   var text=event.feature.getProperty('description');
                });
```

or kml layer:

```
ctaLayer.addListener('click', function (kmlEvent) {
            var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
}
```

instead I would like to take from place_changed event

```
var ac = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

google.maps.event.addListener(ac, 'place_changed', function () {
....
}
```

Any solution?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recovered the values through calls to the api of the fusion tables

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT field FROM key_table WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(' + lat + ', ' + lng + '),1))&key=api_key'

 xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
                xmlHttp.send(null);
                console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
```